# How to best save/store the results from intermediate calls to a recursive function?

Tags: r

I have a function that recursively calls itself:

```
myfunc <- function(id) {
  
  new_id <- id - 1
  
  print(id)
  
  if(new_id > 0) {
    myfunc(new_id)
  }
  return(0)
}
```

If I call it with 2, we get

```
> myfunc(2)

[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 0
```

as expected, but actually I want to somehow save the intermediate values that are printed and return them at the end, as a vector:

```
[1] 2 1 0
```

I tried this:

```
v_id <- NULL

myfunc <- function(id) {
  
  new_id <- id - 1
    
  if(new_id > 0) {
    v_id <- c(v_id, id)
    myfunc(new_id)
  } else {
    return(v_id)
  }
}
```

but it just returns null.

I feel that this can be solved using environments, but I'm not sure at all how to do it.

How can I save the intermediate results of the recursive function call, and return them at the end ? Or if there is a better way to achieve what I want ?

Thanks

Comment: So do you really need a recursive function then? Do you just want to reverse the output?

Comment: @user2974951  I need a recursive function. The actual use case is more complex and this is just a mwe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
myfunc <- function(id) {
  new_id <- id - 1
  print(id)
  
  if(new_id == 0) {
    return(c(id, new_id))
  } else return(c(id, myfunc(new_id)))
}

x <- myfunc(2)
#[1] 2
#[1] 1
x
#[1] 2 1 0

x <- myfunc(5)
#[1] 5
#[1] 4
#[1] 3
#[1] 2
#[1] 1
x
#[1] 5 4 3 2 1 0
```